# Alfresco 5 : Set quota on specific repository folder or users

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm fairly new to Alfresco and just started trying to customize our installation to fit our needs.

One of our repositories can be accessed by somes users only. They are allowed to add files on a specific folder of this repository.

I would like to set a quota so that they won't be allowed to upload too large files.
I've found that it was possible to set a quota for a user but it only applies to "My Files".

How can I do this on a specific folder ? Or for the users, but applied to all directories in which the would add file ?

Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: Might need a custom behaviour or rule?

Comment: Perhaps :). I'm looking for ways to do so.

Comment: Yeah, there's no something that you could use OOTB. I'd suggest taking this and extending it as you like. https://github.com/keensoft/alfresco-myfiles-quota

Comment: I didn't manage to set this up. This remains pending for the moment. I'll come back to it later.